# Start bash shell (cygwin) with correct path without changing directory

Tags: bash, cygwin, environment-variables, working-directory

I need to run a cygwin shell script without changing the working directory, from outside the cygwin environment.

If I run just `\path\to\bash.exe -c command`, then the path is not set correctly and cygwin programs can't be found.

If I use the `--login` option, `bash` sets the path correctly, but also changes to my home directory.

What options should I use to launch bash to keep the current working directory, and also find cygwin executables?

Comment: Hi, similar question was being discussed at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder

Comment: @Roman: This would be totally off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turns out that the cygwin default `/etc/profile` checks for an environment variable named `CHERE_INVOKING` and inhibits the change of directory if set.

So

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1
\path\to\bash.exe -l -c command
```

has the desired behavior.

Comment: This works for invoking MSYS2 bash as well.